# how to change a string to http form in ruby? such as # to %23

Tags: ruby, escaping

How to change a string to http form in ruby?
Such as `#` to `%23`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CGI class to do this

```
 url_encoded_string = CGI::escape("'Stop!' said Fred")
     # => "%27Stop%21%27+said+Fred"
```

Reference http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html#M000067

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Ruby Standard CGI library](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/index.html) escape method:

```
require 'cgi'
CGI::escape("#") // => "%23"
```

Answer (score 1):

[URI::escape](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI/Escape.html) seems to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest

```
URI.escape(foo, Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))
```

its safe to use if you also have URLs in your query params :)